# how to create a column name based on the rows value with tiyverse only

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to create a column name based on the rows values with tidyverse only, in R, obviously.

Here is the sample of the data I have.

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), comorbidity_one = c("Obesity", 
"None", "Diabetes", "Heart Disease"), comorbidity_two = c("None", 
"None", "Obesity", "Diabetes 2"), comorbidity_three = c("None", 
"None", "None", "Obesity")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is how I want the new data to look like:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), comorbiditiy_one = c("Obesity", 
"None", "Diabetes", "Heart Disease"), comorbidity_two = c("None", 
"None", "Obesity", "Diabetes 2"), comorbidity_three = c("None", 
"None", "None", "Obesity"), diabetes_obesity = c(0, 0, 1, 0), 
    heart_disease_diabetes_2_obesity = c(0, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @maydin - obviously nothing as I do not know how to do this :)